# How to get sub items in sencha/extjs

Tags: extjs, sencha-touch

I'm completely new to sencha touch / extJS. I wonder when I derive from a container to build some kind of view and I now add `items`. How can I control those items from inside my view. Do I really need to use `Ext.getCmp` to get those? That kinda seems like an ugly hack because it does not only search through sub components but basically through the whole DOM, right? I wonder if there is another built in way to get the references to the sub items from inside my component.

Comment: no answer? I'm looking at the same problem. I need to get a text field inside a view, but want to do it through the view itself rather than use the static Ext. functions...

Comment: Look at this. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12461802/how-to-cache-subcomponents-instance-inside-components