# Extjs 4: what is the proper way to retrieve components?

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4, components

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Extjs4.1, up() down() versus Ext.getCmp()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11872261/extjs4-1-up-down-versus-ext-getcmp)

I worked a lot with ExtJS (always with version 4) but I still have problems to understand what is the proper way to retrieve components.

There are many ways to do it, both global:

- `Ext.getCmp ()`
- `Ext.ComponentQuery.query ()`

and internal:

- `Ext.container.AbstractContainer.down ()`
- `Ext.container.AbstractContainer.up ()`
- `Ext.container.AbstractContainer.nextSibling ()`
- `Ext.container.AbstractContainer.nextNode ()`
- `Ext.container.AbstractContainer.previousSibling ()`
- `Ext.container.AbstractContainer.previousNode ()`
- `Ext.container.AbstractContainer.child ()`
- `Ext.container.AbstractContainer.findParent ()`
- `Ext.container.AbstractContainer.findParentBy ()`
- `Ext.container.AbstractContainer.query ()`
- `Ext.container.AbstractContainer.queryBy ()`
- `Ext.container.AbstractContainer.queryById ()`

Now, if I use an **id** for every component (like buttons, checkboxes, grids, etc) I'm sure to get them always, even if the layout of main containers change: I can do it following the global way.
However, this kind of search could affect the performance of the application: honestly, I don't know how `Ext.getCmp ()` works but I think that the search is done in the whole variables namespace.

So, this problem led me to follow occasionally the second way.
The problems come when I change the layout of main containers. Take the example as follows:

```
Ext.create ('Ext.panel.Panel', {
    title: 'Main Container' ,
    width: 300 ,
    renderTo: Ext.getBody () ,
    items: [{
        xtype: 'textfield' ,
        fieldLabel: 'First name'
    } , {
        xtype: 'textfield' ,
        id: 'tfLastName' ,
        fieldLabel: 'Last name'
    } , {
        xtype: 'checkbox' ,
        boxLabel: 'Alive'
    }] ,

    bbar: {
        xtype: 'toolbar' ,
        items: [{
            xtype: 'button' ,
            text: 'Get CheckBox' ,
            // Gets the checkbox starting from the second textfield (Last Name)
            handler: function (btn) {
                var tfLastName = Ext.getCmp ('tfLastName');
                console.log (tfLastName.nextSibling ('checkbox'));
            }
        }]
    }
});
```

When I click *Get Checkbox* button it returns the checkbox I requested but If I change the order of *Main Container* items (suppose to put the checkbox declaration before *Last Name* textfield) it returns null, as expected.
Now, this is **the problem**: I don't want to change the logic when I'm changing the view.

**So, my questions are:**

- *Does exist a function that allows me to retrieve components without the use of Ids and to leave unchanged the logic while the view is changing?*
- *Does exist a proper way to do the retrieval of components? If yes, what?*

Comment: See this answer, I think it will help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11872261/extjs4-1-up-down-versus-ext-getcmp/11874707#11874707

Comment: Also this talks about references and refactoring with regards to changes http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12461802/how-to-cache-subcomponents-instance-inside-components

Comment: @DmitryB I didn't see it, thank you!